# To which router I should connect my Wireless High-DB antenna?

Tags: antenna, wifi

Aside from legal concerns, I need technical advice...

I've bought 14db directional ANTENNA:

[image]

Where I can connect that to get that ANTENNA working (to get at least 10-11-12 DB) ?

Can I just remove one antenna from typical wi-fi modem :

[image]
(not actual image of my router)

and connect my new Antenna? or I have to remove both antennas, thus router will concentrate all power into this new one?  (let's say, router's whole power is 15 or 20 DB)

p.s. I am newbie and dont understand the technical answers from you. I just want  to transmitt signal about 30-40 meters far, in this distance there are 3 large stone walls.  I want a simple recommendation: "do this , do that.." to achieve what I want.. I've not yet bought the router (and want not an expensive one).

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your directional antenna?

Comment: @Jeroen3 Extended range in one specific direction?!

Comment: @Jeroen3,  sorry, i dont think your question is appropriate. of course i want an extended range in one direction.

Comment: Disagree with the off-topic vote reason - it's a question on the _modification_ of an electronic device, not the _use_ as such. I agree the question could be better, though.

Comment: @Araho  thanks. if it was about "using", then where I should have opened the topic?  btw, I had technical/electric question, and that's why i have chosen this site. 

what should i do to be a better question?

Comment: @PeterJ I've not bought router yet, that's why i am asking, which one to buy.  (thanks, i've migrated question to SuperUser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some accesspoints allow the antenna array to be configured.
Mikrotik is [an example](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Interface/Wireless) (see "antenna-mode"), DD-WRT also supports this on most hardware.

The accesspoints on your image most likely does not. Change them both, or accept that you will lose half of the [mimo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIMO) performance. Unless your client in is range of both.

How the accesspoint will handle effective the loss of one antenna is unknown.
You could disable mimo by forcing it to 802.11bg only. But unless the firmware has options to disable antennas, you will have to use trial-and-error.

Comment: sorry, I cant understand most part. I am not tech-guy, just can you tell me which router/modem i should buy/get, to use with that antenna?   (p.s. i dont exactly need 14, but let it be 11,12,13 db).

or is there any USB appliances for this?

Please, tell me directly, pointing to items what i should buy.

Comment: @T.Todua I can't answer that, you have to specify your needs. Obviously you want to extend the range, but you didn't specify what for. And those details are important in WiFi networking technology.

Comment: p.s. i want it to transmitt signal about 30-40 meters, in this distance there are 3 large stone walls.

Comment: @T.Todua To get signal trough multiple walls you'd need to put in enough power to correct for the attenuation **from both sides**. Relocate the accesspoints.

Comment: maybe i am on a wrong site. you talk about power, attenuations, accesspoints.. however, i am newbie and dont know what are you talking about. I wanted a simpler recommendation "do this , do that" to achieve what i want..  from my room, i want to aim a place (30 meters from my room) and 3 large stone walls between them.  what should i do ? which appliance i should apply with the above Antenna?

Comment: @T.Todua buy two ubiquiti beams.

Comment: to what to connect them? i couldnt afford them i afraid.. i just wanted to use the antenna i've posted... i thought that was directional and can do what i wanted..

Comment: @T.Todua Then buy mikrotik accesspoints. You set them to single antenna, and you can use own antenna. If you buy 2, and enable WDS, you should be able to get wifi over the 30 meter gap. But, given your lack of commitment to the problem (the question is still on hold) I highly doubt you will get anything working.

Comment: I dont know how to commit more.. i am just a regular consumer, without much technical knowledge in this field, and does a men needs to be a physician or electric, to just use wifi router as he needs? 
Huge thanks Jeroen3 anyway, for the help!